# Snakes and Ladders

Tags: word, steganography, word-ladder

Things are getting a bit puzzly...

Reveal the Ladder and solve the clues to form a Word Ladder.

Find the word that fits in the clue “???”.

One fake clue is here to ruin your day *[laughs wickedly]*

$\color{white}{\textsf{3}}$S$\color{white}{\textsf{1}}$N$\color{white}{\textsf{T}}$A$\color{white}{\textsf{a}}$K$\color{white}{\textsf{9}}$E$\color{white}{\textsf{6}}$S$\color{white}{\textsf{Z}}$

Note:

> All words are of the same length and the altered letter in each round is different.

Hint:

> All clues are given with the correct form/ tense as the intended answer

<sub>This puzzle is a part of [Ooohh, it all makes sense now! :D](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85613/ooohh-it-all-makes-sense-now-d)</sub>

Comment: I don't know word ladders.  They're one letter different at each step?  Does that include the three operations, ADD, REMOVE, CHANGE?  (Yes I have the clues)

Comment: @LeppyR64 I think it's "change" only, since the note says all words are the same length.

Comment: Ah, missed that (how?) thanks @jafe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The word is **LEAD**.
>
>  LeppyR64 found the secret ladder using [bit.ly\31Ta96Z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4d1y.png).
>  SeaMonkey basically solved the ladder, but did not deal with the ??? And fake clue.
>
>  Given the comment that the fake clue does not lead to word, here is the ladder and explanation I arrived at:
>
>  **BEEN** - visited, travelled
>  **BEAN** - a pod of seeds
>  **LEAN** - with little fat
>  **LEAD** - ??? (the answer)
>  **READ** - study for a specialized qualification
>  **ROAD** - route
>  **TOAD** - unpleasant man
>  **TOLD** - gave them instructions or information
>
>  Fake clue = ask for permission or help

Comment: fake clue means a clue that does not lead to a word, not one that leads to a wrong word.

Comment: in other words no BEAD. keep it up!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Do I need to use all the words in the ladder?  For example I can get from word #1 to word #5 in my answer already, if I can discard three words.

Comment: yes, all including ??? and except one fake clue

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Is this now correct?

Comment: yep, well done! will accept later ;)

Comment: @LeppyR64 you basically solved this one. Out of interest, you gave the answer '??? = LEAD', how did you get it without building the ladder?

Comment: @seamonkey it followed the theme of the other answers in the metapuzzle

Answer (score 7):

Partial Answer:

The fake clue is:

> SNAKES - It's actually 3S1NTAaK9E6SZ

bit puzzly...

> [bit.ly\31Ta96Z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4d1y.png)

Clues:

"???" - This is the answer

> LEAD

"a pod of seeds"

> bean

"ask for permission or help"

> seek? plea?

"gave them instructions or information"

> load

"route"

> road

"study for a specialised qualification"

> ?

"unpleasant man"

> toad

"visited, travelled"

> been

"with little fat"

> lean

Comment: I think the one you are missing is simply READ.

Comment: congrats on the steganography part! yet the fake clue is in the ladder. keep it up!

Answer (score 3):

To build on @LeppyR64's answer...

> BEEN  Visited, travelled.
>  BEAN  A pod of seeds.
>  LEAN  With little fat.
>  LEAD - Fake clue  (Ask for permission or help).
>  READ  Study for specialised qualification.
>  ROAD  Route.
>  TOAD  Unpleasant man.
>  TOLD Gave them instructions or information.

Comment: which clue does each word refer to?